# How do I cite range of references?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I have to cite in LaTeX a range of sources (I'm using Miktex 2.9, TexnicCenter and Bibtex), all together.

If I write

```
... in 1990 \cite{ref1,ref2,ref3,ref4,ref5}
```

I would like to get

"... in 1990 [1-5]",

but actually I get

"... in 1990 [1,2,3,4,5]".

Any suggestion? Thank you

Comment: Add to the preamble `\usepackage{cite}`.

Comment: The tags you used suggest that you use `biblatex`. In this case you could use one of the styles anding on `-comp`, which should do what you want. Ideally you would post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) which would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: If - as the biblatex tag suggests - Paolo is using biblatex then the cite package will not be compatible and he should use the correct style e.g. numeric-comp.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you're right. I didn't notice the tag; I just read the question body. I'll clarify this.

Comment: @Paolo Minotti my suggestion about the `cite` package is valid only if you are *not* using `biblatex`. Otherwise, see Ulrike's comment.